# CodeIgniter not pushing variable to View

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

So I'm building an application for users to be able to upload rides to a website and have them be viewable to other users. The only problem is that my controller is apparently not properly pushing the variables to the view making me have an error that reads:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: ridesArray
Filename: views/rides.php
Line Number: 93
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong but here is the code. Also, cause I know it will be asked, yes, my model is returning real data. Also the var_dump() in the view returns null. And the ridesArray() function is just one that makes a neat array with the information gathered from the model and it works. The problem here is that the variable is not getting sent to the view

UPDATE: I've added the code for the function ridesArray(). Also I forgot to mention I am also getting this error:

```
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/rides.php
Line Number: 96
```

Controller:

```
function index(){
    $userrides = $this->RidesModel->getAllRides();
    $rideData = $this->ridesArray($userrides);
    $ridesArray = array('ridesArray' => $rideData);
    $this->load->view('rides', $ridesArray);
}
function ridesArray($data){
    $newarray = array();
    foreach($data as $object){
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);

        $id = (int)$array['id'];
        $title = $array['title'];
        $date = $array['date'];
        $ridetime = $array['ridetime'];
        $saddress = $array['StartAddress'];
        $scity = $array['StartCity'];
        $sstate = $array['StartState'];
        $szip = $array['StartZip'];
        $ezip = $array['EndZipcode'];
        $ecity = $array['EndCity'];
        $image = $array['image'];

        $newdata = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'title' => $title,
            'date' => $date,
            'ridetime' => $ridetime,
            'StartAddress' => $saddress,
            'StartCity' => $scity,
            'StartState' => $sstate,
            'StartZip' => $szip,
            'EndZipcode' => $ezip,
            'EndCity' => $ecity,
            'image' => $image
        );
        array_push($newarray, $newdata);
    }
    return $newarray;
}
```

Model:

```
    function getAllRides(){
    $sql = "select * from rides order by date";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 user-cont">
<ul class="container col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">

    <?php
    var_dump($ridesArray);

    if(isset($ridesArray)){
        foreach($ridesArray as $out){
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<h3>".$out['title']."</h3>";
            echo "<img class='img-responsive img-thumbnail' src=". base_url(). "uploads/".$out['image']."/>";
            echo "<p>".$out['date']." At ".$out['ridetime']. "</p>";
            echo "<p>Starts At ".$out['StartAddress']." ".$out['StartCity']."    ".$out['StartZip']." "."</p>";
            echo "<p>Ends At ".$out['EndCity']." ".$out['EndZipode']."</p>";
            echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: So what if you do this?  `$data['ridesArray'] = $rideData;  $this->load->view('rides', $data);`

Comment: try  $result = $query->result_array();

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what Sparky said in his comment.

Change

```
$ridesArray = array('ridesArray' => $rideData);
```

to

```
$ridesArray['ridesArray'] = $rideData;
```

That will get rid of the error.

Comment: I wasn't sure my comment was the answer. I actually thought the array variable and the inner key sharing the same name, `ridesArray`, was the root problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate about how using this alternate method to assign the value makes a difference?

Comment: I just tried this. Not sure why but it's still returning null. Is there anything in the config or autoload files that I need to add to make this work or should these things just be sent to the view regardless? I also tried to do

    $ride = 'ride'
    $this->load->view('rides', $ride);

And then a var dump in the view then nothing happened still

Comment: You are not still getting the "Undefined variable" message are you?

Comment: Yup still getting the Undefined Variable message and when I do the var_dump() I get "null" in the browser

Comment: What is the code for `$this->ridesArray()`?  Please edit your question to include that method.

Comment: Okay will do. Let me know what you think. Also, an error I am getting is "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Change your return result into `$result = $query->result_array();` or in your view change all your column in `$ridesArray->column_name`

Comment: I don't think you get what the error is telling me though. It's saying that there is nothing being sent to the view. Even if I make up something like $ride['example'] = "example"; it will still come up with that error.

Comment: What the heck is in your database? In `index()` please add `var_dump($rideData);` after the line `$rideData = $this->ridesArray($userrides);` and show us at least part of the output.

Comment: Lol that var_dump showed nothing in my view. And I ensure you that the database has items in it.

Comment: I'm sure there is data in the database. I want to see what it is. That var_dump won't make your code work but will let us see what the data structure is your are trying to use.

Comment: Yeah but for some reason that var_dump() didn't pass on to the view

Comment: It won't pass into the view but it should still display in the browser - above everything that the view provides. Add the line `echo "var dump follows";` above the line `var_dump($rideData);` Do you see it in the browser? Is there anything after it?

Comment: Nope absolutely nothing. Which is what I'm finding odd. I've coded an application similar to this before in codeigniter and never had these issues

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the true issue here is that nothing is getting sent to the view. Hence the error 

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: You don't even see the `echo "var dump follows"` output? Or do you see that but nothing after it?

Comment: Nope literally nothing. Which is odd. I've done a var_dump in the controller before and never had this issue.

Comment: Wierd. Try adding 'exit()' after var_dump